# Is there a way to change vendor extension CSS with Java Script?

Tags: javascript, css

This works:

```
document.getElementById("elementid").style.animation = "aniname 1s infinite";
```

But this doesn't:

```
document.getElementById("elementid").style.-webkit-animation = "aniname 1s infinite";
```

Comment: it was `element.style.webkitAnimation`